# is_file($file) returns false on IIS

Tags: php, iis

While trying to upload image on iis server through php
The is_file() and file_exist() functions return false even if the file exists.
Some times it returns true also(1 in 10 times)

php version 5.2.x
windows server IIS

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo 'is_file:' . (is_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) ? 'true' : 'false');
        echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo 'file_exists:' . (file_exists($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']) ? 'true' : 'false');
    }

?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>"enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="myfile" />
            <input type="submit" name=submit />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

bugs reported on php.net https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37118

can anybody provide solution other than upgrading or changing language or server

Comment: What does `echo $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` say?

Comment: changing directory permissions already tested. Will admin and full permissions also the problem persists

Comment: C:\temp\php7A0.tmp       ....... temp directory has all permissions and also other destination directories

Comment: try (is_file($file) && is_uploaded_file($file))

Comment: is_file returns false but is_uploaded_file returns true and (is_file($file) && is_uploaded_file($file)) returns false

Comment: Does `is_writable('C:\\temp\\')` return true?

Comment: is_writable('C:\temp')   returns true

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=37118 check this link for reported bug

Comment: MAKE A NOTE THAT THE FILE GETS UPLOADED BUT STILL THOSE FUNCTIONS RETURN FALSE

Answer (score 0):

> can anybody provide solution other than upgrading or changing language or server

Well ... you could track down the cause of the bug, and fix it yourself.

Seriously.  That is a solution.

This (apparent) bug has been sitting in the PHP issue tracker since 2006.  Surely *someone* could find out what the real problem is.

(Given the symptoms you describe, it seems like something is caching file metadata, and the `is_file` and `file_exists` tests are looking at stale information.  Well that's a theory ...)

Comment: the file gets uploaded successfully everytime but the is_file and file_exist return false...... but some attempts they return true... but again return false for same file also

Comment: plz if any body finds out the solution any day.... update it here...its desparately needed

Comment: @Sachin9 - Did you actually read what I wrote in my answer?  If you are truly desperate ... fix the problem yourself.

Comment: I didnt find fix myself @Stephen thats why i am here to ask for help.

Comment: @Sachin9 - So you have downloaded the PHP source code?  Read it to work out how those functions are implemented?  Built it?  Run it using a debugger?  I'm not saying "find" a fix.  I'm saying **develop** a fix.  'Cos I suspect that if you wait for someone to do the work for you, you could be waiting a LONG time